# configuration-snippet annotation doesn't add custom header to response

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I need add response header "X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow". Ingress controller contains directive `more_set_headers "X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow";`. But in response I don't see it.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: development-ip
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_set_headers "X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow";
  name: front-ingress
  namespace: staging
spec:
  rules:
  - host: somedomain
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: front-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /*
      - backend:
          serviceName: backend-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /api/*
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - somedomain
    secretName: front-tls-secret
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can try to use `server-snippet`:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  server-snippet: add_header X-Robots-Tag “noindex, nofollow”;
```

for a snippet in the nginx config service block.

Or you can add it to a specific ingress using `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet`:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |-
  add_header X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow";
```

for a snippet in the nginx config service block.

Please let me know if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

The problem: cluster have 2 ingress controllers nginx/gce. Annotations was applied to nginx ingress controller, but traffic was via gce ingress controller.